# Custom Test Adapter is not showing tests on Test Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-test-runner

I am trying to implement a custom Test Adapter, all the files are bellow:

- [TSTestDiscoverer.cs](http://pastebin.com/UYdS0Tcg)
- [TSTestExecutor.cs](http://pastebin.com/YAWXzLcM)
- [TSTestContainer.cs](http://pastebin.com/H02Npyzg)
- [TSTestContainerDiscoverer.cs](http://pastebin.com/D6uP0G7J)
- [VsSolutionHelper.cs](http://pastebin.com/8VH9wgkp)<sup>[from XMLTestDiscoverer source code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/31/writing-a-visual-studio-2012-unit-test-adapter.aspx)</sup>

Using

```
vstest.console.exe /listdiscoverers /usevsixextensions:true
```

I confirmed that the extension is installed and it is listed on the test discoverers.

Running

```
vstest.console.exe file.ts
```

I confirmed that both `TSTestDiscoverer` and `TSTestExecutor` are working correctly.

Now I want to list the tests on Test Explorer, for that I guess I need `ITestContainer` and `ITestContainerDiscoverer`. I tried to implement both, but something is not working, the Test Explorer does not show any tests...

What did I do wrong? How can I find out what is not working?

Comment: Implementing the interfaces and having the Export doesn't work for me. I have `File.WriteAllText` calls to check that any of the code is hit but it doesn't happen. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to add an attribute on the class that implements `ITestContainerDiscoverer`.

```
[Export(typeof(ITestContainerDiscoverer))]
```

Now it is working.

Comment: Where on earth is the documentation for this kind of stuff? I saw a few samples, but just samples, isn't there a documentation for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the blog post here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2012/05/17/content-index-for-unit-test.aspx as very useful.  It contains links to most of the MS stuff on unit testing, including the extension building. It also seems to be updated.

The post by the Chutzpah creator, Matthew Manela, is also very useful http://matthewmanela.com/blog/anatomy-of-the-chutzpah-test-adapter-for-vs-2012-rc/