# Test discovery in visual c++ Makefile project configuration

Tags: c++, unit-testing, makefile, visual-studio-2013

I have a c++ unit test project in visual studio 2013 that has

```
Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type
```

set to **Makefile**. I have also specified the output directory under

```
Configuration Properties -> General -> Output Directory
```

and the output file name under

```
Configuration Properties -> NMake -> Output
```

I have built the project successfully and I see the dll in the output folder. However, the test explorer is not able to discover any of the unit tests.

Is there a way to enable test explorer to discover tests in a dll that was built by Makefile/NMake? I tried creating a custom ITestDiscoverer but that code wasn't even invoked by VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an `ITestContainerDiscoverer` (on the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544530/custom-test-adapter-is-not-showing-tests-on-test-explorer)) and made this discover the unit test dll's that were created by the MakeFile build process. The built-in discoverer in Visual Studio apparently doesn't support MakeFile builds.

The custom `ITestContainerDiscoverer` that I created had to have the same Executor Uri as that used by the Cpp unit test framework, namely "`executor://CppUnitTestExecutor/v1`".